# Function parameter with asterisk and ampersand

Tags: c++

I have a function here at work and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Can someone explain what this code is doing?

```
unsigned int Function( BYTE *&, BYTE );
```

I have never seen a parameter with `*&`. It is used on multiple functions. I've tried looking in books for answers and looking online. I can't find any information on this format and what it is doing.

Any help I would appreciate it.

Now I have seen functions with the use of `*` and `&` but never together like above.

Also, I know the return value is unsigned `int`. :)

I'm mostly just asking about the one parameter.

Thanks

Comment: pass in a pointer to byte by reference and pass in the second input of byte by value.

Comment: can you give me an example please ?

Comment: It means that Function can modify not only the contents pointed by the first parameter, but also the address to which is pointing.

Comment: As a side note, the 'c' tag should be removed from this question.

Answer (score 4):

In declaration

```
unsigned int Function( BYTE *&, BYTE );
```

the `*&` stands for *pass pointer by reference*, what means that changes made to pointer inside this function will be made to original pointer and not to its *copy*. You would want to pass a pointer by reference if you have a need to modify **the pointer** rather than the object that the pointer is pointing to.

@FredOverflow's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20188970/1141471) follows:

```
template< typename T>    
void paranoid_delete( T *&p)
{
    delete p;
    p = nullptr;
}
```

You can also pass a pointer by pointer which can look like this:

```
void freeAndZero( void** ptr)
{
    free( *ptr);
    *ptr = 0;
}
```

Without the reference, you would only be changing a local copy of the pointer, not affecting the caller.

Comment: Is there another way of doing the same thing? Like declare **ptr and pass it as &ptr?

Comment: @Pepsi_1 yes, exactly as you said, explanation added

Comment: So is the programmer using this * & syntax so he doesn't have to deference the pointer inside the function while checking the pointer for different characters like %, ' ', '*' and so on? I'm still trying to wrap my head around why someone would want to do this.

Comment: @Pepsi_1 yes, this might be the case, but to fully answer your question you would have to paste Function() code

Answer (score 3):

Composing simple things to make complex systems is probably the most important concept in programming.  Let's break down what is happening here.

You know that if you see `BYTE*`, that type is "pointer to BYTE".

Now if you see `T&`, you know that is "reference to T".

When these get combined, making `T` equal to `BYTE*`, you get `(BYTE*)&`.  Due to the grammar grouping rules, `BYTE*&` means the same thing.  And the meaning remains "reference to something... and something is pointer to BYTE".

(note that grammar grouping rules are important... `const T` with `T` of `BYTE*` is written as `const (BYTE*)` or `BYTE* const`, but not the same as `const BYTE*`)

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int Function( BYTE *&, BYTE );
```

The first parameter is of type "reference to pointer to `BYTE`". Read it from right to left, it will be easier to understand.

```
BYTE * &
^    ^ ^
|    | |------ Reference to  
|    |------- Pointer to
|----------- BYTE (duh).
```

You can also use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) and substitute `BYTE` by `char` and `Function` by any letter in the declaration:

> declare f as function (reference to pointer to char, char) returning
>   unsigned

Answer (score 0):

Parse the parameter expression from right to left: `BYTE * &` is a reference to a `BYTE *`. Right-to-left parsing is often useful with pointers and references.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the first parameter is `BYTE *`, or `BYTE * &`, you still pass a pointer of type `BYTE *` as the first argument from the caller.

The ampersand in the first parameter allows the  `Function`  function to **change the address the pointer refers to**.  Any modification of the first parameter  changes the address of the first parameter from the point of view of the calling function.

If the first parameter's type had been  `BYTE*` rather than  `BYTE *&`, the parameter would also be the address at which a  `BYTE` was stored.

```
unsigned int Function( BYTE *&, BYTE );
```

This function can be invoked as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    BYTE  b;
    BYTE* ptrToByte;
    unsigned int FunctionResult;
    b = 22;
    ptrToByte = &b;
    FunctionResult = Function(ptrToByte, b);

    /* At this point, ptrToByte may or may not have */
    /* changed, depending on what lines of code the Function function */
    /* executed */
}
```

---

**Other Notes**:

- Passing an argument by reference is not supported in the C language; this function prototype is valid for C++, but not for C.

It is considered a good idea to put the name of each arguments (not just the data type) in the function prototype:

[Put name of parameters in C function prototypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174886/put-name-of-parameters-in-c-function-prototypes)