# Practical Applications or Value of Function Prototype Scope

Tags: c, formatting, arguments, prototype

First off: When searching for answers, I am allowed to [tag] the areas to search. This posting interface should support that too.

Besides error checking which only requires types, not identifiers, what are some of the practical applications one might encounter for leveraging function prototype scope? What are some of the advantages to this?

```
function(int index, float array[index]);
//function prototype with names
```

vs

```
function(int, float);
//function prototype(without identifiers)...
```

The definition of a function always includes the return argumen, function name and function arguments including the type and names It seem that having a prototype scope would be redundant since the arguments are re-declared anyways with names:

Prototype:
    return_type return_name(argument_type, ...);

Function Declaration:

```
return_type return_name(argument_type argument_name, ...){
    compound_statement_function_block;
}
```

The only value I can see is that it reserves the function name within the file scope namespace meaning the function name could be used within the prototype:

```
int func(int func);    //Proto type declaration. Compiler allows this
                       //but throws warning about func() redeclaration
                       //but nothing about the arguments.

int function(int function){
    int function;
}
```

I had originally thought that the scope was independent of names meaning file_scope_variable_name was different than file_scope_function_name. They are contextually and significantly different enough to be such and I thought that is what the standard called for however the compiler I am using, gcc, won't allow it. It will however allow main re-declared as a tag in the struct/union name space at any scope since they a block element like a function:

```
int func(int func){
    typedef struct {
        int func;
    };                 //Cannot use func as a variable name at function scope 
                       //since it is an argument even though 
                       //this is within a different namespace
    typedef union func{
        int (*func)(int func); //Shows func() name and arg. names
                               //are different namespaces.
        union u{
            int func;
            //...
        }
    } ;
}

int main(int main){
    typedef struct main {
        int main;
    };
}
```

It seems 'main' is a reserved keyword at the file level for variable names and function names but not struct/tag union names. It accepts this at the file level:

```
struct main {
    int main;
    //...
} not_main;
```

It makes no sense why the namespaces are as such for the prototype. If it didn't have some practical utility, it wouldn't be a distinction.

Comment: A function has global scope, so does not need leveraging. You can unleverage it by defining it as `static`.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Are you asking what the differences/merits are between having named args vs unnamed args in the function prototype?

Comment: The declarations are not the same: the first has (effectively) a `float*` parameter, the second has a `float`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put name of parameters in C function prototypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174886/put-name-of-parameters-in-c-function-prototypes)

Comment: Function prototype scope is the scope of the parameters of the function. The first example is related to that. The second is not. Your question is confusing. Obviously having a first parameter declare a size and the next array being that size has merit in a function. The compiler can enforce type checking on the parameters and you can create stronger function specifications that way.

Comment: I am just inquiring as to why there are two distinct namespaces. One being function scope and the other being function prototype scope. Is declaration of a function, which includes the return type, name and with argument type and names the prototype scope? Is the attached block contained within return_type identifier(arg_type arg_name){statements;} considered the function scope? That would basically be: function_prototype_scope{function_scope}

Comment: There is no global scope, @WeatherVane.  A function identifier has scope determined by its location, like any other -- either file scope or block scope in the particular case of function names.  Additionally, function identifiers have *external linkage* by default, but this is a separate consideration from scope.

Comment: @JohnBollinger *external linkage* is what I meant.

Comment: Doesn't a header file create global scope where all variables defined there in are included in the whole program when a separate file #includes that header? This is probably just semantics. Are individual files with variables and other elements at file scope in the translation unit excluded beyond that individual file? Regardless, I am a hobbyist and just curious and I cannot find  a legitimate reason for there to be a prototype declaration scope separate which is separate from the function definition scope.

Comment: No, @pchelper4, there is no global scope in C.  A header file provides a convenient means to make identical file-scope declarations in different translation units, each of which has its own, separate file scope.  Among other things, this is useful for enabling code in one translation unit to access functions and variables declared in others, but that's a question of *linkage*, not scope.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thank you for the clarification on headers and scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### Preliminary

You are mixing several distinct concepts that apply to C identifiers: *scope*, *namespace*, and *linkage*:

- **Scope** is the region of program text where a given association between an identifier and a particular program entity is visible and can be used.
- **Namespace** describes the fact that C allows the same identifier to be used in the same scope to identify objects in certain contextually distinguishable categories: labels, tags, structure and union members, and everything else.
- **Linkage** is about whether a variables or function declared in one translation unit can be accessed from others (external linkage), or only from elsewhere in the same translation unit (internal linkage), or only within the scope of its definition (no linkage).

Scope and linkage are substantially separate considerations.  File scope declarations of ordinary identifiers can have either external or internal linkage.  Block scope declarations of ordinary identifiers can have either external linkage or no linkage.  All declarations of identifiers in other namespace have no linkage.

---

### The question

... is a bit wide-ranging, but I'll try to hit on the main points.

> Besides error checking which only requires types, not identifiers,
> what are some of the practical applications one might encounter for
> leveraging function prototype scope? What are some of the advantages
> to this?

Having a function prototype scope makes it possible to include parameter names in function prototypes.  If the prototype did not provide a scope for the function parameter identifiers, then the only scope to which they could belong would be file scope, and that would imply that every parameter name would have to be distinct from every other in the file, and from that of every file-scope variable.  It would also imply that function parameters could be accessed from outside the function.  And of course there would be an issue with multiple declarations of a function that provide different parameter names.  What a mess!

It is true that you don't *need* prototypes that are not part of function definitions to provide parameter names -- that is optional, after all.  But allowing it is a great convenience for everyone.  Among the benefits are

- it makes it easier to create separate prototypes (just take the one from the function definition and remove the function body)
- it makes function prototypes far more meaningful to human readers, especially with good choices of parameter names
- it allows compilers to provide more useful diagnostic messages

> The definition of a function always includes the return argumen,
> function name and function arguments including the type and names It
> seem that having a prototype scope would be redundant since the
> arguments are re-declared anyways with names

You seem to be looking at it backward.  One of the effects of function prototype scope is that giving parameter names in a prototype *isn't* redundant.  Except for prototypes that are part of a function definition, the scope of the identifier declarations in a function prototype is the prototype.  They don't have to match from one prototype of a given function to another (though typically they do).  The only parameter names that matter to the function body are the ones associated with the function's definition.

But for the reasons given earlier, among others, we generally *want* parameter names to appear in function prototypes.  Especially so in prototypes appearing in headers or otherwise used in translation units different from the one containing the function definition.

> The only value I can see is that it reserves the function name within
> the file scope namespace meaning the function name could be used
> within the prototype

It *does* have that effect, though I rarely see a function's identifier used as the name of one of its own parameters.  But it's a bit more common that a file-scope function name appears also as the name of some other function's parameter.  Or that a file-scope variable name appears as the name of a function parameter.

> I had originally thought that the scope was independent of names
> meaning file_scope_variable_name was different than
> file_scope_function_name.

No, that would be a question of namespace.  Function and variable names belong to the same namespace (that of ordinary identifiers), which is appropriate because they are not always distinguishable from each other by context.

> [my compiler] will however allow main re-declared as a tag in the struct/union name space at any scope since they a block element like a function

Yes, `main` can be used as a tag, despite also being the identifier of a function with external linkage.  And also as a label and as a member of arbitrarily many structures and unions.  **This is because those are separate *name spaces***.  Rather than trying to learn a rule for how namespaces are established, it is probably best to just remember the different namespaces -- other than those of all the structures and unions, which can be taken as a category, there are only three.

Also, `main` can be used as a parameter name in a function prototype or as a local variable of a function, **because such identifiers have different *scope***.

And `main` can be used as the name of a separate (file-scope) function in as many different translation units as you like, so long as no TU has more than one, and **provided that exactly one in the whole program has external *linkage***.

Comment: Good info, thank you! I liked the f(x) as paramerter names distinction, good point no matter ho subtle. To recap, it sounds like namespace applies to what and scope applies to where more or less. On creating separate prototypes with different  bodies, do you mean that they also have different names within the same file scope or use pre-processor conditionals if different files have functions of the same name in a header? What do you mean blocks have external linkage? Are the three name spaces aside from union, struct and enum member identifiers: labels, tags and ordinary(variables, functions)?

Comment: P.S. The main source of information for reference and examples I have been using is "https://en.cppreference.com/w/c" and C Programming, 2nd ed. by Kernighan. If you know of an equivalent or better source you could recommend for Standard C, please let me know!

Comment: @pchelper4, Yes, it is reasonable to say that namespacing is about what (kind of thing) is named, whereas scope is about where the name appears.  Everything I said refers to C source code as it would be after all preprocessing (not just conditional compilation but also `include` processing and macro expansion).  Yes, the three namespaces other than those of struct and union members are labels, tags, and everything else.  But no, enum constants are ordinary identifiers; enums don't have members.

Comment: And I'm sorry, but we are explicitly and intentionally not in the business of recommending off-site resources here.

Comment: OK, thank you! Where could I go on this site to get that question answered? Is buying the standard worth the money for a hobbyist?

Comment: No, @pchelper4, I would not recommend that someone in your position buy the standard, but if you search around the web you can probably fund a free copy of a late draft C11, and maybe the same for C18 (which is basically a maintenance release, anyway, with no new features).